# Object distortion in WPF when switching to different monitor screen size

Tags: c#, wpf, screen, distortion

I am new to WPF, my question is :

I have an application in which there is a circle object which carries some information and I would like to drag and drop it.
My problem is when i run it on my computer it works fine, but when I change the screen size circle object shape get distorted and become ellipse.

I am using grids with 5 rows and column with equal ratio(*).

Is it something when screen size changes its inch(physical size) length != breadth.

Please give your expert advice.

(Edit1 : Tried in Canvas, in canvas circle looks like circle irrespective of any screen but wondering how this is implemented in grid !)

`

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="257*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="121*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="442*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="520*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="121*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="865*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse Name="ellipse2" Stroke="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />   </Grid>
```

`

I know I am doing wrong as when resolution changes ratio changes which gives different physical units for different screen. Please suggest the better way using grids.

(Edit2 : According to ben solution here below is the result comparison, in my case example 3 i wuld prefer, but had to take care abt that stroke somehow!!)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QpRR.jpg

Comment: Somewhat related: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/44241/Align-Stretch-WPF-Buttons-Using-XAML

Comment: @Tico ty for reply, but my problem is in my screen it works properly but when i change screen somehow ratio of column and rows changes which makes my circle looks like ellipse .. :(

Comment: Note that WPF is DPI aware, if you set your grid definitions with `*` it will expand/reduce accordingly!

Comment: @Tico Yeah I know, so wat I could do make a circle look like circle .. irrespective of any screen...
Is there something dynamically change ratio on screen changing event or something ...

Comment: or I have to leave the grid and and switch to canvas.. pls give ur tips on that....

Comment: Although "not recommended", you could fix the circle `Width` and `Height` =/

Comment: K just for test I tried canvas and in canvas circle look circle in different screen size.. but wondering how its possible in grid...

Comment: Could it be a wrong resolution configured in Windows ? For instance, imagine your screen has a native resolution of 1280x800; if you configure a resolution of 1280x720, everything would be distorded, including the circle in your app.

Comment: Please insert sample code in you question

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon you are absolutely correct about the resolution.. 
Now I want my application to be resolution independent .. in my case a circle should look like a circle irrespective of screen and also its should zoom up or down according to the resolution or monitor size.. Pls reply asap

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon I have added the sample code.. I hope I have clarify my question .. waiting 4 ur response eagerly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i'm not really sure of what you're trying to do, so here are several solutions. They all use `Grid` since you specifically asked for it. However, I'm not convinced that it's really appropriate.

Your problem is that the `Ellipse` size is determined by the `Grid`, and there is no constraint to force the aspect ratio. So the aspect not only changes when the screen resolution is different, it also changes when you resize the window.

### Solution 1 : set Width and Height of the Ellipse

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="257*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="121*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="442*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="520*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="121*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="865*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20" />
</Grid>
```

### Solution 2 : set the Width and Height in the Grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="257*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="442*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="520*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="865*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

### Solution 3 : use a ViewBox

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="257*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="121*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="442*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="520*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="121*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="865*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Width="20" Height="20" />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

### Solution 4 : bind ellipse Width and Height together

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="257*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="121*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="442*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="520*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="121*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="865*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Stroke="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
             Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
</Grid>
```

### Differences

Solution 1 and 2, both give a constant size to the circle, whatever the `Grid` size is.

Solution 3 and 4, both resize the circle depending on `Grid` size.

Solution 3 will also change the thickness of the stroke, whereas solution 4 wont.

EDIT: Fixed solution 4

Comment: solution 3 .. is pretty much close to what i wanted... 
actually I wanted something like width value should dynamically change depend of screen size....Here in all examples u put size of circle fixed.. but solution 3 automatically zooms up depending upon grid size.. only drawback is the stroke .. is there is something to reduce the stroke thickness..

Comment: Ty so much .. for your answer .. Please look at this picture it consist of details what i require http://i.stack.imgur.com/1QpRR.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Another way to zoom up circle without distortion is apart from viewbox:
'

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="257*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="121*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="442*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="520*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="121*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="865*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Uniform"  />
```

'

Unlike Viewbox which place circle in the middle of the grid, this Stretch = "Uniform" stretches the circle and place it left of the grid. But shape remain same for all screens.
Its basic, I dont knw how I forget this.